# What are the standard names of the protocols behind UseOAuthAuthentication and UseGoogleAuthentication?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core, openid, openid-connect

The ASP.NET Security Social Sample [has two ways to interact with Google.](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/4927ad6b7413c5ef6d91fb264c00e350e3a15a8b/samples/SocialSample/Startup.cs#L92-L121)

UseOAuthAuthentication

```
app.UseOAuthAuthentication(new OAuthOptions
{
    AuthenticationScheme = "Google-AccessToken",
    DisplayName = "Google-AccessToken",
    ClientId = Configuration["google:clientid"],
    ClientSecret = Configuration["google:clientsecret"],
    CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-google-token"),
    AuthorizationEndpoint = GoogleDefaults.AuthorizationEndpoint,
    TokenEndpoint = GoogleDefaults.TokenEndpoint,
    Scope = { "openid", "profile", "email" },
    SaveTokens = true
});
```

UseGoogleAuthentication

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOptions
{
    ClientId = Configuration["google:clientid"],
    ClientSecret = Configuration["google:clientsecret"],
    SaveTokens = true,
    Events = new OAuthEvents()
    {
        OnRemoteFailure = ctx =>
        {
            ctx.Response.Redirect("/error?FailureMessage=" 
                + UrlEncoder.Default.Encode(ctx.Failure.Message));
            ctx.HandleResponse();
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
});
```

**What is the standard name for these two types of authentication and authorization?** I.e. is one OAuth and the other OpenID Connect?

When choosing to `UseOAuthAuthentication`, this is the result.

```
context
    .User.Claims: []
    .User.Identity.Name: null
    .Authentication.GetTokenAsync("access_token"): ya29.CjAlAz3AcUnRD...
    .Authentication.GetTokenAsync("refresh_token"): null
    .Authentication.GetTokenAsync("token_type"): Bearer
    .Authentication.GetTokenAsync("expires_at"): 2016-07-19T22:49:54...
```

When choosing to `UseGoogleAuthentication`, this is the result.

```
context
    .User.Claims: [
        nameidentifier: 10424487944...
        givenname: Shaun
        surname: Luttin
        name: Shaun Luttin
        emailaddress: admin@shaunl...
        profile: https://plus.google.com/+ShaunLuttin        
    ]
    .User.Identity.Name: "Shaun Luttin"
    .Authentication.GetTokenAsync("access_token"): ya29.CjAlAz3AcUnRD...
    .Authentication.GetTokenAsync("refresh_token"): null
    .Authentication.GetTokenAsync("token_type"): Bearer
    .Authentication.GetTokenAsync("expires_at"): 2016-07-19T22:49:54...
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `UseOAuthAuthentication` and `UseGoogleAuthentication` are OAuth. The difference is that the Google middleware sets some default OAuth options that are specific to Google and adds a `GoogleHandler` that gets the user profile information.

In other words,

- `UseOAuthAuthentication` is OAuth that retrieves and access token.
- `UseGoogleAuthentication` is OAuth with its options and flow tuned to retrieve an access code and user profile information from Google.